# Closure compiler with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I'd like to compile this Node.js module (just for type checking)

```
var externalRequire = require;
var Pool = externalRequire('pg-pool');

var config = {};
var pool = new Pool(config);

module.exports = {};
```

with these Closure compiler's options:

```
java -jar compiler.jar
--js_output_file output.js
--use_types_for_optimization
--warning_level VERBOSE
--jscomp_warning=reportUnknownTypes
--jscomp_warning=checkTypes
--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
--process_common_js_modules
--externs externs.js
--js src.js
```

externs.js contains only one definition:

```
/**
 * @param name
 * @return {*}
 */
var require = function(name) {}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to explain to Closure compiler that "Pool" is not an instance of object, but type.

```
src.js:5: WARNING - cannot instantiate non-constructor
var pool = new Pool(config);
           ^
src.js:5: WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
var pool = new Pool(config);
           ^
0 error(s), 2 warning(s), 88,9% typed
```

How to avoid these errors?